# Поддерживает ли атрибут "action" тега <form> множественные параметры?

Tags: html, form, action

Есть форма из которой информация отправляется в файл  благодаря чему на почту приходит уведомление. Мне необходимо добиться того что бы помимо mail.php задействовался еще один файл, выполняющий другую функцию. Можно ли в атрибуте action перечислять файлы через запятую или использовать несколько action?

Comment: Во-первых, нельзя. Во-вторых, что мешает прописать запуск нужной функции внутри этого самого mail.php?

Answer (score 1):

В action несколько путей написать нельзя, но можно на JavaScript-е написать функцию, которая по одному клику будет отправлять несколько запросов. Проще всего это сделать на JQuery.

Принцип действия:

1. Убираем action у формы вообще.
2. Вешаем на кнопку событие onClick="НазваниеФункции()"
3. Пишем функцию НазваниеФункции():
4. Получаем значения всех input-ов по их id
5. Формируем get или post запросы на нужные адреса

Всё это достаточно легко и просто гуглится, к тому же вы лучше запомните, если разберетесь и сделаете сами, вместо копи-пасты готового кода. Направление я указал, действуйте. Удачи в обучении!